# How to design and train my own convolutional neural network in Matlab using Caffe package?

Tags: matlab, conv-neural-network, caffe

I have a structure for my CNN that will be used in image enhancement. and I want to know how to use Caffe package in Matlab to design and train the network. I don't need to import pretrained network from Caffe as I have a specific structure for the CNN. Does any one have a link or example that guide me on how to do that? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The Caffe official documentation has a simple example showcasing basic interfaces for Matlab including adding conv layers to the network:

http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/tutorial/interfaces.html#matlab

Once you get the basics for matlab, the interfaces are mostly similar to python.
Hope that helps